# What is the case for using html-codes when any Unicode character can be encoded in UTF-8?

Tags: html, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I read [Joel Spolsky's article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) on characters and encoding (twice), and I am enlightened.

I don't get why people on the Internet use HTML code encoded in UTF-8 in their HTML documents, such as

```
&#39;
```

for making the browser display an [apostrophe](https://unicode-table.com/de/0027/)?

Citing Joel:

> "UTF-8 was another system for storing your string of Unicode code points, those magic U+ numbers, in memory using 8 bit bytes."

Now: Let's say I am writing a blog (that is: I create a string), I decide to use Unicode characters, select one that I want to have printed on the screen, decide that it is a good idea to represent it as an HTML code rather than "the letter itself", encode it in UTF-8, send the bytes over the Internet to someone, let this person's browser decode the bytes, and let said browser decode the characters (again) to display an apostrophe.

Why would anyone want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three scenarios where it is useful to use a character reference:

- When you aren't encoding the document in a Unicode encoding (hopefully you won't be this century)
- When you are using a character with special meaning in HTML (such as a `'` inside an attribute value delimited by `'` characters)
- When you don't have a keyboard layout with which you can type the character you want to use

Comment: Points 1 and 3 are quite clear. Does this: `<meta name="twitter:description" content="If USA Hockey isn&#039;t interested in obeying the law, its players aren&#039;t interested in competing."/>` qualify as an example for point 2?

Comment: Since it is delimited with `"` and doesn't use `"` in the value. No. `data-name='Pete "The Butcher" O&#039;Shaughnessy` would.

Comment: Great, I get it. So in conclusion: In my example there's no need for html-codes, so it was essentially used carelessly. But in yours it was needed, because `data-name='Pete "The Butcher" O'Shaughnessy"'` would be broken.

Comment: @johelmuth HTML is often generated rather than typed. When I code in PHP and I inject plain text into HTML I simply call [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars); I don't care fiddling with the second parameter to determine what exact characters among the 5 possible ones get finally encoded because it's not worth it.

Comment: #4 When it is a non-printable character and you don't want to delete it inadvertently #5 When your editor cannot display the emoji you've managed to type